# Apache POI with Content Navigator Plugin

Tags: content-management-system, ibm-content-navigator

I'm trying to use apache poi libraries to read excel file which gets uploaded by users. I'm using below jar files
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-examples-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.7-20101029.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
The program which reads excel file runs fine locally i.e. as a standalone java.
Issue happens when I deploy this class part of Plugin and I keep getting error message as

```
CIWEB Error: [user_name @ 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] com.ibm.ecm.util.PluginUtil.invokeService()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
```

I tried changing the libaries bu no luck.

Regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

I found a working answer. Added all the required jars under WebSphere lib folder and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the libraries to your Websphere lib folder, i'd suggest creating a "shared library" in websphere. It would allow you to place your POI libraries in a custom folder that you can link to the navigator.war (or to the JVM if you require the POI libs in multiple apps)